# Set and remove read only JavaScript - Unable to do both

Tags: javascript, settimeout, readonly

So this is my first attempt at JavaScript (learning Java atm) and I'm almost finished. What I want to do is: Remove readonly from my textarea at page refresh, and after some minutes set it to readonly with timer.

All the timers, getElement-parts, and readOnly-attributes seem to be working (finally).

JavaScript:

```
<script>
//x = Timelimit in minutes, z = Time remaining alert in minutes
function timeLimit(x,z) {
    var min = 60 * 1000;
    var limit = x * min;
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Du har " + z + " minutter igjen på prøven.") },( limit - (z * min) ));
    setTimeout(function(){ alert(x + " minutter har gått.\nTiden er slutt.") },limit);
    setTimeout(document.getElementById('testroom').setAttribute('readOnly','readOnly'),limit);
}
</script>
```

Here's the call for my function (put it below my textarea since it seemed to be the only way for getElement to find my textarea by id):

```
    <form method="post" action="insert.php" />
        <textarea name="content" id="testroom"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send inn for retting" />
    </form>

<script>
timeLimit(0.2,0.1);
document.getElementById('testroom').removeAttribute("readOnly",0);
</script>
```

If I move the removeAttribute above the timeLimit() (or put it inside the function), my textarea will stay readonly=true. If I put it below, it will stay readonly=false, even after 12 seconds (0.2 minutes, where the timer is supposed to happen).

Hopefully someone can clear this up for me, been searching a trying a lot of different syntax.

Comment: note: 0.2 mins are 12 seconds, not 20 ;)

Comment: ah yeah.. its getting late :P thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your third setTimeout() call is not doing what you want.  Instead it is executing the .setAttribute() method immediately.  You should wrap it in a function to get it to execute later.

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert(x + " minutter har gått.\nTiden er slutt.") },limit);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('testroom').setAttribute('readOnly','readOnly')},limit);
```

Even better, you could combine the two, but make sure to put the setAttribute call first so the user can't sneakily kill your JavaScript at a bad time:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('testroom').setAttribute('readOnly','readOnly');
    alert(x + " minutter har gått.\nTiden er slutt.");
},limit);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Working now.
It's kinda obvious to me now why it changed by moving the remove-part above or below now.. When I refreshed the page I thought the readonly was still set since the last time I ran the script (like SESSIONS), but I guess thats not how JavaScript works.
Looks like I don't need to removeAttribute at all. Better get some sleep hehe..